# Developing android apps on Android x86

Tags: android, android-x86

I'm looking for some resources about developing android apps using Android x86 as I don't have an android device and the emulator is way to slow to be able to use. Anyone have any resources or advice for trying to do this?

Comment: I can't directly answer your question but I can with authority say you should invest in at least one android device if you plan to develop for it.   If for nothing else, it will give you one single live testbed, but more importantly you can ascertain the norms of the OS via interaction with the core apps and the ones provided in the market.

Comment: Yeah, probably. But I also don't have any money to buy one. Hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your whole development is not targeted at the hardware platform, but at Dalvik (the virtual machine), you shouldn't have any problems developing for Android on x86 the same way you do it for mobile. My guess is that you might find trouble when you decide to do more advanced things like using the NDK,as there you're dealing with native code, but it probably shouldn't be a problem if you have experience with linux programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources I came across after I quick search:

http://androiddevnotes.com/2011/03/08/1299521520000.html

http://www.mat-d.com/site/developing-android-apps-with-android-x86-and-virtual-box/

Answer (score 0):

some companies provide "cloud" access to real mobile devices for testing purpose.
I just googled  http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/android.html but I did not use it. There are probably competitors with similar services.

Comment: Seems line a good idea but looks very expensive. For that price I could just buy an android device which is what my problem really is.

Comment: cloud testing might be relevant for ARM devices. But for x86 devices, As ThomasW suggested , virtual machine is probably the cheapest solution.